# Thumbnail of share point files

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, office-365, client-object-model

I want to display the thumbnail of SharePoint image or pdf file. In Google Drive case from Thumbnaillink we are getting thumbnail URL. Like that is there any property or api is available in SharePoint?

Comment: Please elaborate your question more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the preview image feature of the Office Web Apps server:

For a document located here:  https://yourServer//sites/training/Shared%20Documents/Report1.pdf

use:

```
https://yourServer/sites/training/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=/sites/training/Shared%20Documents/Report1.pdf&action=imagepreview
```

Comment: using client object model how i can retrieve thumbnail url?

Comment: Directly from CSOM? I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft added a thumbnail expression for this:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#filepreview